# EF Core System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am getting this error mentioned in the title. The same code works for the first API call, but not for the 2nd call. It fails on the 2nd `SaveChangesAsync()` call

```
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I am using

```
services.AddTransient<ProjectContext>();
```

in my `startup.cs`. I tried `AddScope` but it doesn't work.

Error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
> Object name: 'ProjectContext'.'

Code:

```
private readonly Action<InjectedControllerArgs, ProjectDto, NavigationElements> _postAfterSave = async (injectedControllerArgs, dto, nav) => {
var memberClient = new MemberClient { MemberId = member.MemberId, 
                                      InvitationEmail = member.Email, 
                                      ClientId = dto.ClientId, 
                                      LastModifierId = member.MemberId };   
await dbContext.MemberClient!.AddAsync(memberClient).ConfigureAwait(false);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
             
var role = await dbContext.Role.Where(r => "client-admin" == r.RoleCode)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                               .ConfigureAwait(false);
await dbContext.MemberClientRole!.AddAsync(new MemberClientRole
                                               { LastModifierId = member.MemberId, 
                                                 MemberClientId = memberClient.MemberClientId, 
                                                 RoleId = role.RoleId })
                                 .ConfigureAwait(false);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); }


    public async Task<ActionResult<ProjectDto>> PostInsertAsync(int customerId, int clientId, ProjectDto dto)
    {
        if (dto == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dto));
        dto.CustomerId = customerId;
        dto.ClientId = clientId;
        return await _pmBaseController.PostAsync(new NavigationElements(customerId, clientId, null), Topic, dto,
            _returnOne, _postBeforeSave, _postAfterSave).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> PutAsync(NavigationElements nav,
        TopicName topic,
        int id,
        TDto dto,
        Func<InjectedControllerArgs, NavigationElements, int, Task<T>> returnOne,
        Func<TDto, int, TDto>? putBeforeSave = null,
        Action<InjectedControllerArgs, TDto, NavigationElements>? putAfterSave = null
    ) ...
```

Comment: any help will be appreciated.  No idea how to tackle this one

Comment: I guess your provided code is in an async method, are you awating this method from where it gets called?

Comment: I do use async.  I will add more code to show why something else may be the issue

Answer (score 2):

Your `_postAfterSave` delegate is asynchronous but does not return a `Task` which effectively means it is `async void` so your `_pmBaseController` is unable to await it which means execution will proceed before this `Action` is done. That the first SaveChanges works is timing / coincidence.

Try changing the type from `Action<InjectedControllerArgs, ProjectDto, NavigationElements>` to `Func<InjectedControllerArgs, ProjectDto, NavigationElements, Task>` and make sure to await it everywhere.

Comment: thanks for that. I will try it soon and let you know. thanks so much